# Dropdown closes on its own

Tags: .net, asp.net, html, drop-down-menu

Hi I have a dropdown on page.
When I click on dropdown to select some value, the dropdown list open and then closes on its own.
I have to repeat this 4-5 times to select a value.
For info :- the data binds with dropdown on runtime through database.
Can anybody guide me what might be the problem with this.

Comment: What does your code look like? ...

Comment: Do you have a js Onclick event that sets focus?

Answer (score 2):

"what might be the problem with this"

The problem with this *might* be that your dropdown is loosing focus *somehow* after you click / select it.

Answer (score 0):

It probably is a javascript problem.
Look in your page and check if a javascript closes the Dropdown on opening. You can view the bound events to your dropdown by using [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event).

Or maybe your mouse dbl clicks instead of single click. :)

Answer (score 0):

At first please provide the code. In my guess you will be binding the code of DropDown on PostBack rather than (!IsPostBack) and make sure that the autopostback of DropDown is set to true.